# Binary Tree Leaves

Tags: binary-tree, nodes

Question: assuming a binary search tree has 5 leaves, what is the minimum number of levels that it could have?

I thought a leaf was a node that did not have any children, and when I approached this problem I got 6 levels, but the answer is 4. Can someone explain this?

My process:

```
           50
          /  \
         30  Leaf
        /  \
      Leaf 40
          /  \
         35  Leaf
        /  \
       33  Leaf
      /  \
    Leaf  34
```

I might be doing something wrong visualizing the tree, if that's the case please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be nodes with two leaves.

```
    10
    /\
   21 22
   /\   /\
  L  L 31 L
       /\
      L  L
```

Comment: What would be the height of that tree?

Comment: Seems like 4 to me

Comment: So like 10 is one level, 21 and 22 another, and so on?

Comment: Yes. I just numbered nodes. These are not values.